# pairs() how to give different labels a different font style?

Tags: r, plot, graph, visualization, correlation

In a correlogram created by pairs(), I want the first, second, and fifth label in regular font (font.label=1); the third cursive (font.label=3); the forth and sixth label in bold font (font.label=4). I managed to give the different histograms a different color, yet I fail to do the same for the label fonts.

Changing font.label changes the font style of all labels and does not accept more than one number. When trying to create my own text.panel function I can't figure how to make the font style dynamic.

Reproducible code:

```
data("USJudgeRatings")
correlation <- USJudgeRatings[1:6]

clrs <- RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(n = 6, name = "RdBu")

panel.hist <- function(x, ...) {
  usr <- par("usr")
  on.exit(par(usr))
  par(usr = c(usr[1:2], 0, 1.5))
  his <- hist(x, plot = FALSE)
  breaks <- his$breaks
  nB <- length(breaks)
  y <- his$counts
  y <- y/max(y)
  c <<- c +1 
  rect(breaks[-nB], 0, breaks[-1], y, col = clrs[c] , ...) #different color per histogram
}


c <- 0
pairs(correlation,
      na.action = na.omit,
      diag.panel = panel.hist,# Adding the histograms
      #text.panel =   #Can we do something here? 
      #font.labels = c(1,1,3,2,1,2),   #Only takes one number
      cex.labels = 2,
      oma=c(1.4,1.4,1.4,1.4))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you suggest, you can provide a custom function for `text.panel`:

```r
c <- 0
pairs(correlation,
      na.action = na.omit,
      diag.panel = panel.hist,# Adding the histograms
      text.panel = function(x, y, labels, cex, font, ...) 
        text(x, y, labels, font=c(1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2)[c]),
      cex.labels = 2,
      oma=c(1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4))
```

It uses the same global variable `c` as your `panel.hist()` function. I can't say I am too happy about such a solution (and naming a variable `c` is not a particularly good idea either) but it does get the job done.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was so close, yet so far away... (Out of curiosity: what is the problem with naming a variable `c`?)

Comment: I can quote Hadley Wickham's [Style guide](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Style.html) here: *Where possible, avoid using names of existing functions and variables. Doing so will cause confusion for the readers of your code.* `c()` is an R function which combines its arguments so it's better to reserve `c` for this. In your case, I would go with `i` as the variable name.